# How to get the tagName of an element with no identifier or css classes using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Using selenium how do I fetch a html tags element, the html tag does not have any unique identifiers, below is the html code:

```html
<form data-v-48e2f75a="">
   <header data-v-48e2f75a="">
      <h4 data-v-48e2f75a="">via email</h4>
   </header>
   <div data-v-48e2f75a="" class="form-wrap">
      <div data-v-cccee08c="" data-v-48e2f75a="" class="input-wrap email-input" type="email">
         <label data-v-cccee08c="">
            <div data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-inner-wrap has-icon">

               <!--The below input tag is one of the tags I need to fetch-->
               <input data-v-cccee08c="" placeholder=" " type="email"> <i data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-label-icon icon-envelope-o"></i> <span data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-label">Your E-mail</span> <!---->
            </div>
            <!----> <!----> <!---->
         </label>
      </div>
      <div data-v-cccee08c="" data-v-48e2f75a="" class="input-wrap password-input" type="password">
         <label data-v-cccee08c="">
            <div data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-inner-wrap has-icon">
               <input data-v-cccee08c="" placeholder=" " type="password"> <i data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-label-icon icon-unlock"></i> <span data-v-cccee08c="" class="input-label">Your Password</span> <!---->
            </div>
            <!----> <!----> <!---->
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p data-v-48e2f75a="" class="secondary-utilities forgot-password"><span data-v-48e2f75a="">Forgot password?</span></p>
   <footer data-v-48e2f75a="" class="form-footer">
      <div data-v-48e2f75a="" class="secondary-utilities registration">
         <p data-v-48e2f75a="">Don't have an account?</p>
         <span data-v-48e2f75a="">Sign up new account</span>
      </div>
      <button data-v-48e2f75a="" class="app-button rose-button min-width">Sign in</button>
   </footer>
</form>
```

How I have been trying to get the element / things I've  tried:

```java
    public static boolean login(WebDriver browser, String email, String password){
        List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='email' or @type='password']"));
        System.out.println();
        for (WebElement element : elements){
            System.out.println(element.getTagName());
            System.out.println(element.toString());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

however the above method keeps returning null, below are some of the other methods I've  tried:

```java
List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.id("input[type='email']"));
```

```java
List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector("*[type='email']"));
```

```java
List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.cssSelector("*[type='email']"));
```

The tag is surrounded by some dividers...

Comment: Not able to reproduce. The first (xpath) example returns a non-null element list. Can you add more of the HTML context to the question?

Comment: @andrewjames done, the whole form tag is surrounded by like 3 - 6 separate divs.

Comment: OK - thank you for the update. I am still not able to reproduce the problem. When I use your code, it correctly finds the 2 expected input fields (email and password). I print out the HTML using `System.out.println(element.getAttribute("outerHTML"));`. How do you set the `browser` object? Something like `browser.navigate().to(url);`? Are you opening the correct HTML page?

Comment: @andrewjames like this: `browser.get("https...");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the elements are [React](https://reactjs.org/) elements as well as `<input>` elements to extract the `<tagName>` of the element using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491), you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) and the *type* attribute of the `<input>`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("//[type='email'][placeholder]"))).getTagName());
  ```
- Using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and the text *Your E-mail* of the `<span>`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Your E-mail']//preceding::*[@type='email' and @placeholder]"))).getTagName());
  ```

Comment: I am trying to get the `<button>` tag but its returning the element not found exception, your method worked with the other tags but not this one sadly. (error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: app-button rose-button min-width (tried for 20 second(...)`)

Comment: @Aasil Your question was for an `<input>` tag, right? Is the `<button>` tag some other element? Can you raise a new question please?

Comment: When I try `browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("app-button rose-button min-width")).click();` it returns: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: app-button rose-button min-width`, I'd appreciate some assistance with this <3

Answer (score 0):

Should it be like this?

```
  List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
```

Instead of:

```
  List<WebElement> elements = browser.findElements(By.id("input[type='email']"));
```

Because your element has no "id" attribute, you can't find it by By.id.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']"));
    WebElement passwordElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']"));
```

Or if you want to get a list of elements, use this:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']|//input[@type='password']"))
```

Comment: Hi, I added the `emailElement` object and it couldn't   find the element, the exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: //input[@type='email']`